# SQL query with average subquery

Tags: mysql, sql

I am making a SQL query towards a weather database, i need the wind_direction and windspeed.
This is my currect query:

```
SELECT wind_direction,
       windspeed
  FROM weather
  WHERE time >= curdate() and
        time < (curdate() + interval 1 day) AND
        windspeed > 0
  ORDER BY wind_direction ASC
```

This will remove all values where windspeed = 0 and will only show data for today.

Query output:

```
wind_direction   windspeed  
0               10.1  
0               11.2  
23              7.6  
23              1.4
```

As you can see i get duplicate values which is understandable, but my graphing system does not support this, it does not know which value to use.
What i need is one unique wind_direction and the avg() windspeed for that direction.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
SELECT  wind_direction, AVG(windspeed)
FROM    weather
WHERE   time >= curdate() and time < (curdate() + interval 1 day)
        AND windspeed > 0
GROUP BY
        wind_direction
ORDER BY
        wind_direction ASC
```

If you want a single `wind_direction`, say, that with the greatest average speed, use this:

```
SELECT  wind_direction, AVG(windspeed) AS avg_speed
FROM    weather
WHERE   time >= curdate() and time < (curdate() + interval 1 day)
        AND windspeed > 0
GROUP BY
        wind_direction
ORDER BY
        avg_speed DESC 
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: Is that correct, how does mysql know which AVG(windspeed) to use when it groups the data?

Comment: @HyperDevil: from `GROUP BY`, it tells which records to combine (sharing the same values of `wind_direction` in your case).

Comment: but there are multiple wind_directions in the select?

Comment: @HyperDevil: yes there are, but they are unique. Please post some sample data and the resultset you'd like to get.